# Laravel 8 jobs not dispatching

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have this Job

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Http\Traits\CreateTrait;

class CreateJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels, CreateTrait;

    protected $contactForm;

    public function __construct($contactForm)
    {
        $this->contactForm = $contactForm;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        //This connects to SSH and takes 5-10s
        $this->CreateOnetime($this->contactForm->room_id, $this->contactForm->company_id, $this->contactForm->id);
    }
}
```

Then I try in controller

```
use App\Jobs\CreateJob;
class ContactFormController extends Controller
{
    public function save(StoreContactFormRequest $request, $cid, $rid){
        $validated = $request->validated();
        $validated['room_id'] = $rid;
        $validated['company_id'] = $cid;
        $contactForm = ContactForm::create($validated);
        CreateJob::dispatch($contactForm);
        return back();
    }
}
```

Nothing written in the DB, though I have `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` in the .env file.
The function runs synchronously, so it does not create the Job somehow, just runs it.

Comment: you import use App\Jobs\CreateCodeJob; but the name of the class is CreateJob ... this is a typo?

Comment: @Prospero Yes, my bad, a typo.

Comment: Php artisan queue:work

Comment: @Savlon I think this is for running these jobs, problem for me is they are not created.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was I had `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync` somewhere after `QUEUE_DRIVER=database`